# bootstrap, How to place text over image in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bots

[image]I have a col-md-6 div with an image already place inside the div, and i need to place some text specifically under the logo in the image. every attempt keeps placing it under the image, please help . i have no css in place yet

```html
<div class=".container-fluid">
  <div class="set7">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <img src="images/dpfront1.png">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2016 DepotSquare.All Rights Reserved. </h6>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>


  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use z-index, position: absolute etc. You'll need to do some custom CSS rather than relying on the framework

Comment: im not to familiar with positions yet, but i know i can put the z-index for the img at -1 and then the text at maybe 10. but how would you call that specific image and that specific text in the css?

Comment: You'd use IDs if they aren't being used anywhere else, as you can't repeat IDs across the DOM

Comment: also consider a background image

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}
#img_head {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 10px; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class=".container-fluid">
  <div class="set7">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center image">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JhISDA9aj1Q/UTECr1GzirI/AAAAAAAAC2o/5qmvWZiCMRQ/s1600/Twitter.png">

        <div class="col-md-6" id="img_head">.col-md-6
          <br />
          <h6>Copyright &copy; 2016 DepotSquare.All Rights Reserved. </h6>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>



  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Replace `.col-md-6` with whatever text you want.

Comment: yes, but the reason i did a col-md-6 , is to place another col-md-6 div beside it and fill it with a form field. could your code be revised, so its not full width but just half?

Comment: If you want two things then you will get the text on the left & a space on the right!

Comment: @Joel put up what exactly you want. Your question is unclear, text over the image or under the image, in the center or to the left??